# array in for loop [x1,x2,x3,x4] into [x1,x2] [x2,x3] [x3,x4] (Python)

Tags: python, arrays

That is my sample code that works fine, but i'm asking my is there a "better" way to manipulate the loop to get the same result. The value of (old,value) are coordinates to draw a line from point 1 to point 2 ...from point 2 to point 3 and so on.

> ```
> old = []
> for index, value in enumerate(data):
>     if N.size(old)>0:
>         print old,value
>     old = value
> ```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> zip(a[:-1], a[1:])
[(1, 2), (2, 3), (3, 4)]
```